# best practice for android screen switch

Tags: android, performance

I am aware of the different methods for switching back and forth between android screens. I was wondering wich method, if any, is the best practice for doing so. Switching activites seems to be the most popular, but how processor friendly is it?

EDIT:
 This question seems too objective, so I guess I will modify it by asking if anyone knows what method is most processor friendly.

Comment: Just curious, but how else would you "switch between screens" anyway? I can only think of.. perhaps using one activity while animating in and out multiple fragments, or using one activity and animating views in and out in one layout. 

Either way, using multiple activities helps with organization, app/code clarity, and is the way Android apps are meant to be constructed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, apps are typically separated by multiple activities. These days, the activities contain fragments to better support multiple devices, layouts, etc. They are popular for a reason!

It's all very friendly. ;)